# Why snmpget output is different when MIBS environment variable is defined?

Tags: linux, snmp

```
$ export MIBS=
$ snmpget -Oqv -v 2c -c public 10.xxx.yyy.zzz .1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.1.14.3.2.0
"ACTIVE"
```

but

```
$ export MIBS=F5-BIGIP-SYSTEM-MIB
$ snmpget -Oqv -v 2c -c public 10.xxx.yyy.zzz .1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.1.14.3.2.0
ACTIVE
```

Why that difference in output when MIBS environment variables has a  value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SNMP mib defines the data types for your SNMP OIDs, so with the MIB loaded it can display a "formatted" version of the value rather than displaying the raw value.

For example, compare:

```
MIBS= snmpget -v2c -c public 192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.1 = INTEGER: 24
```

With:

```
$ snmpget -v2c -c public 192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.1
IF-MIB::ifType.1 = INTEGER: softwareLoopback(24)
```

When mibs are loaded, `snmpget` knows how to interpret the value.

---

In the particular case in your question, the mibs says, "display that value as a string".

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific.

Without MIB documents, an SNMP tool can only tell the very basic data types defined by the protocol itself,

- INTEGER
- OCTET STRING
- NULL
- OBJECT IDENTIFIER
- IpAddress
- Counter32
- Gauge32
- TimeTicks
- Opaque
- NetAddress
- Counter64

Since data are encoded in ASN.1 BER, the decoding algorithm can extract such data types from raw bytes over the wire.

Thus, when you run NET-SNMP's `snmpget` command without MIB documents, it merely decodes the data as OCTET STRING and prints as `"ACTIVE"`.

However, MIB documents in SMI v1 or v2 allow customized data types to be defined upon such basic types via the so-called "Textual Conventions". And in your case, MIB document `F5-BIGIP-SYSTEM-MIB` defines the object `.1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.1.14.3.2` as below,

```
sysCmFailoverStatusStatus OBJECT-TYPE 
    SYNTAX LongDisplayString
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
        "The failover status on the system."
    ::= { sysCmFailoverStatus 2 }
```

The actual data type is `LongDisplayString` defined in `F5-BIGIP-COMMON-MIB`,

```
LongDisplayString ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    DISPLAY-HINT "1024a"
    STATUS       current
    DESCRIPTION  "A longer version of SNMPv2-TC::DisplayString."
    SYNTAX       OCTET STRING (SIZE (0..1024))
```

Thus, when you ask NET-SNMP `snmpget` command to load MIB documents, it is fully aware of the data type of `LongDisplayString` and prints `ACTIVE`.

So, you see even the only observable change is just the quotes, a lot happens behind the scenes.